# Uninstall Vaio Premium Partner

Tags: sony-vaio

I am trying to uninstall marketing tools on my Vaio, such as Vaio Premium Partner.
The uninstaller in the appwiz.cpl starts, but the application is always there.

Comment: I assume the question is: `How do I actually remove it?`.  You may need to open your task manager and kill it before trying to run the uninstaller.

Comment: Get the free program "[Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/)" and search for the word "Vaio", and delete everything there after you uninstall it. Then restart your computer.